# how to pass parameters to my thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have a program I wrote in C# with a window.

I have a button that do some things (it doesn't matter what exactly) and it refresh the window in his loop (in button_click function) (with this.Invalidate(false); (I don't use this.Refresh because I have a groupBox that I don't want to refresh)).

I cant minimize the window while the button_click function working, and the window is "stuck".

I am trying to to the code of this button in a different thread, but its have xome problem with dealing parametrs from the main form.
lets say I have this code:

```
void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*want to put this in new thread*/
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = int.Parse(somelabel_num.Text);
    int i;
    OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
    file.ShowDialog();
    if (file.FileName == "")
        return;
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(file.FileName);
    groupBox1.BackgroundImage = image;

    for (i = 0; i < int.Parse(somelabel_num.Text); i++)
    {
        somelabel.Text = i;
        this/*(main form)*/.Invalidate(false);
        progressBar1.PerformStep();
    }
    /*want that here the new thread will end*/
}
```

so how to do this as a thread that gets the paremeters (progressBar1, groupBox1 and somelabel)?

Comment: threads share memory space. what sort of problem are you having? Were is the code that is spawning threads?

Comment: please look on my edit to the question (I edited the code with two "/**/" (the butten_click function is in MainForm (the main form of the projects (a windows project) and there is no other threads).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ParameterizedThreadStart Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx) which accepts type object as parameter.  So you can create your own class that contains 3 properties (progressBar1, groupBox1 and somelabel), and pass that object to your thread, and there you can cast it back to your class type and do anything you would like.

You just changed your question and I see that you would like to put middle part on separate thread, and you would like that thread to interact with thread.  Remember on UI only one (Main) thread can deal with UI, and not worker thread.  Worker thread should be responsible for some calculation/work, but not UI interaction (ShowDialog in your case).  You should consider to change your logic what your background should do.

Read [Updating the UI from a Secondary Thread](http://Updating%20the%20UI%20from%20a%20Secondary%20Thread) by Ted Pattison on how to call UI from another thread.  In WindForms it is not that easy, in WPF it is much easier.

Comment: thank you. I dont sure how to do that. can you edit my code (in the question) as he will include those changes you suggested?

Comment: I want to pass UI parameters (progressBar1, groupBox1 and somelabel) to the thread, and than the thread can affect the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```
void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
file.ShowDialog();
if (file.FileName == "")
    return;
else
 {
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(file.FileName);
    Thread t = new Thread (new ParameterizedThreadStart(MyFunction));
    t.Start (new MyClass(progressbar1,groupbox1,label1,image));

 }
}
```

target function is here:

```
void MyFunction(object obj)
{
MyClass myc= (MyClass) obj;
myc._mypbar; /*can access varriables*/

/* your logic*/

}
```

Class encapsulating ProgressBar, GroupBox, Labels:

```
public class MyClass
{ 
public ProgressBar _mypbar;
public GroupBox _mygpb;
public Label _mylbl;
public Image _myimg;

public MyClass(ProgressBar pbar,GroupBox gpb, Label, lbl,Image img)
{
this._mypbar = pbar;
this._mygpb = gpb;
this._mylbl = lbl;
this._myimg = img;
}
}
```